# How to run a infinite angular forEach loop in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop

```
InstitutionStructure.teamHierarchy().then(function(response) {
    $scope.hierarchyList = response.data;

    $scope.hierarchyListsData = _.where($scope.hierarchyList, {reportingMemberId: null});

    angular.forEach($scope.hierarchyListsData, function(value1, key1) {
        value1.teamMember = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.hierarchyList, function(value2, key2) {
            if(value1.teamMemberId === value2.reportingMemberId) {
                value1.teamMember.push(value2);
            }
        })
    })
```

From the above code I have loaded my hierarchyListsData continuously and I have to fetch list that corresponds to have teamMemberId which is equal to reportingMemberId till the object has no other corresponding values. Please help to find the solution.

Comment: The `foreach` loop is not infinite by definition (unless you have an infinite list, right?).

For what you are trying to achieve, there is a design pattern already for you: Proxy object. Which is to observe and take action on the items that enter into an array.

See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Seems like you want a recursive solution to go through everything in the hierarchy until there is nothing left.